# Unable to return Open CV mat from native C++ to Java in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android application that needs to do some image processing. I am calling c++ code through JNI from java for it. I am using OpenCV for image processing. First, I confess that I just started using OpenCv and learning image processing. What I am trying to do now is trying to return open CV mat data from the native C++ to Java.

I am not a C++ developer as well. I am following this link- http://answers.opencv.org/question/12090/returning-a-mat-from-native-jni-to-java/.

This is my native C++ code

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring



JNICALL
Java_media_memento_memento_SphereCameraActivity_stitchPhotos(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, jlong addrMat, jlong addrNewMat) {




    Mat& mat = *(Mat*)addrMat;
    Mat& newMat = *(Mat*)addrNewMat;

    newMat.create(mat.rows, mat.rows, mat.type());
    memcpy(newMat.data, mat.data , mat.step * mat.rows);

    std::string hello = "Stitching the photo in C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

As you can see, this line

> memcpy(newMat.data, mat.data , mat.step * mat.rows);

will pass the new value to the mat in the java. This is my Java code.

```
               Mat mat;

               bitmap.getHeight();
               bitmap.getWidth();
               mat = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
               mat.put(0, 0, jpeg);
               Mat newMat = new Mat();
               stitchPhotos(mat.getNativeObjAddr(), newMat.getNativeObjAddr());
```

According to my code, when I call native function from Java, newMat variable in java should get the other mat variable value. Right? But when I run that code, my application crashes. 
It is giving me this error

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: media.memento.memento, PID: 4823
                  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (39397) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (3)
                      at org.opencv.core.Mat.put(Mat.java:1011)
                      at media.memento.memento.SphereCameraActivity$MyCameraListener$1.onBitmapReady(SphereCameraActivity.java:276)
                      at com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraUtils$1$1.run(CameraUtils.java:95)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe `newMat.create(mat.rows, mat.rows, mat.type());` should be `mat.rows, mat.cols` unless your image is square. You can set logcat filter to `NO FILTER` and look for crash report (something with SEGFAULT in it), native crashes are shown differently from java ones. [Example of what you should see as error](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aq0ZEvrvRrs/VxuuvvRYKNI/AAAAAAAADBY/YLqFx9qNbK4VTYit5Whh8D40NlbRy10ZACLcB/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2559-04-24%2Bat%2B12.17.15%2BAM.png)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I tried your solution and it is still throwing error. Bu I am able to log the error now and updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java call stack is pointing to this line before the `stitchPhotos()` call even happens:

`mat.put(0, 0, jpeg);`

Based on the error message, `jpeg` has the wrong dimensions.  It appears that `put()` expects to receive an array that is a multiple of 3 in size (since `mat` is declared as type `CV_8UC3`, which is 8 bit, unsigned, with 3 channels per pixel).

P.S.  An easier way to copy one `Mat` to another in C++ is `copyTo`, or the assignment operator.  Examples:

```
Mat& mat = *(Mat*)addrMat;
Mat& newMat = *(Mat*)addrNewMat;
mat.copyTo(newMat);
newMat = mat;
```